# how to load passenger from apache with rvm and unique gem sets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, passenger, rvm

I have two websites running on the same server. Both use passenger and rvm. Each website has a unique rvm gemset. The problem I'm running into is how I would configure passenger to start up in apache.

Here's my apache passenger configurations:

```
ubuntu@www01:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled$ ls passenger.*
passenger.conf  passenger.load

ubuntu@www01:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled$ cat passenger.conf 
PassengerRoot /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@snowcrash/gems/passenger-3.0.2
PassengerRuby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.8.7-p334@snowcrash/ruby

ubuntu@www01:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled$ cat passenger.load 
LoadModule passenger_module /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@snowcrash/gems/passenger-3.0.2/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

You can see from above, that I've configured apache to load the passenger module/configurations from the ruby-1.8.7-p334@snowcrash rvm gem set. My problem lies in having an additional gem set for my other website, ruby-1.8.7-p334@pixel-pets. I've thought about installed passenger in the global gem set, but I think it would see issues when it tries loading gems unique to my project specific gem sets.

Here are my installed gems for each project:

```
ubuntu@www01:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled$ rvm use 1.8.7@snowcrash
Using /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334 with gemset snowcrash
ubuntu@www01:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled$ gem list -l

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.11)
actionpack (2.3.11)
activerecord (2.3.11)
activeresource (2.3.11)
activesupport (2.3.11)
daemon_controller (0.2.6)
fastthread (1.0.7)
file-tail (1.0.5)
haml (3.0.25)
hpricot (0.8.4)
mysql (2.8.1)
passenger (3.0.2)
rack (1.1.2)
rails (2.3.11)
rake (0.8.7)
spruz (0.2.5)

ubuntu@www01:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled$ rvm use 1.8.7@pixel-pets
Using /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334 with gemset pixel-pets
ubuntu@www01:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled$ gem list -l

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.8)
actionpack (2.3.8)
activerecord (2.3.8)
activeresource (2.3.8)
activesupport (2.3.8)
backports (1.18.2)
border_patrol (0.1.0)
bson (1.3.0, 1.1.1)
bson_ext (1.3.0, 1.1.1)
faker (0.3.1)
jnunemaker-validatable (1.8.4)
mongo (1.1.1)
mongo_mapper (0.8.6)
nokogiri (1.4.3.1)
plucky (0.3.7)
rack (1.1.2)
rails (2.3.8)
rake (0.8.7)
will_paginate (2.3.12)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/passenger/

In your `.rvmrc` do:

```
if [[ -s "/Users/sutto/.rvm/environments/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@my-app-name" ]] ; then
  . "/Users/sutto/.rvm/environments/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@my-app-name"
else
  rvm --create use  "ree-1.8.7-2010.02@my-app-name"
fi
```

Or just create it with:

```
cd path/to/project && rvm use ree-1.8.7-2010.02@my-app-name --rvmrc --create
```

Then in each rails project, add a new file `config/setup_load_paths.rb` and add

```
if ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'] && ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'].include?('rvm')
  begin
    rvm_path     = File.dirname(File.dirname(ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME']))
    rvm_lib_path = File.join(rvm_path, 'lib')
    $LOAD_PATH.unshift rvm_lib_path
    require 'rvm'
    RVM.use_from_path! File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__))
  rescue LoadError
    # RVM is unavailable at this point.
    raise "RVM ruby lib is currently unavailable."
  end
end

# Select the correct item for which you use below.
# If you're not using bundler, remove it completely.
#
# # If we're using a Bundler 1.0 beta
# ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = File.expand_path('../Gemfile', File.dirname(__FILE__))
# require 'bundler/setup'
#
# # Or Bundler 0.9...
# if File.exist?(".bundle/environment.rb")
#   require '.bundle/environment'
# else
#   require 'rubygems'
#   require 'bundler'
#   Bundler.setup
# end
```

Of course you should replace `/Users/sutto/.rvm` by your rvm path, and `ruby-1.8.7-p334@snowcrash` by the correct gemset.

Comment: Thanks, Pablo. That worked, but had to create a config/setup_load_paths.rb for each project. Also used cd ~/snowcrash/ && rvm use 1.8.7@snowcrash --rvmrc --create to create the .rvmrc for _each_ project dir.

Comment: Glad it worked. I've just updated the answer with your additions.